Filling multiple columns at once with polars' map_elements
Following up on this question, can I use polars' map_elements to fill multiple columns at once.
Say I have a custom python function
def my_complicated_function(row):

     # ...

     return value1, value2, value3

and I would like to use this as follows
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
      .map_elements(my_complicated_function, return_dtype=pl.Int64)
      .alias("column1", "column2", "column3")
)

except alias does not make multiple columns at once. Can I use struct here for the output as well, or is there something else?

Your function returns list of values, so you have to call it accordingly:
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
      .map_elements(my_complicated_function, pl.List(pl.Int64))
      .list.to_struct(fields=["column1","column2","column3"])
      .alias("result")
).unnest("result")

Or, if you can change your function so it returns dictionary:
def my_complicated_function(row):

     # ...

     return {"column1": value1, "column2": value2, "column3": value3}

You can get return value into struct directly, so you have names of the columns defined inside of your function and then pl.DataFrame.unnest()
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(pl.all())
      .map_elements(my_complicated_function, return_dtype=pl.Struct)
      .alias("result")
).unnest("result")


Thanks a lot for your answer! This does not work for me so far, no new columns are created. I do not get error messages either however. Does map_elements() suppress them?

What might happen is the types of the elements if the list do not match return_dtype. You could try removing return_dtype parameter to see if it works
